# Problem with subdivision modifier making a hard edge have curves between each vert

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I have encountered a problem while using the subdivision modifier I also have on it a mirror modifier (image below of their hierarchy if that is what's effecting the outcome)

[image]

The outcome is that there is a wave like texture/look to the asset. image blow is it without the the wire mesh on and the one below that is with it on. I have tried changing the subdivision mod to being simple but to no avail and I have tried to move the verts about to make them able to work without the weird bendy waves and again to no avail.

[image]
[image]

Thank you for reading.

Edit the fix I had found was that the creases was only marked at 98% which was the culprit to there being the wavy lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the fix I had found was that the creases was only marked at 98% which was the culprit to there being the wavy lines.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks more like the topology of your mesh needs some improvements.

Look at this two images and the way they look with a subdivision modifier because of the topology.

[image]

[image]