# How to achieve crease subdivision

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I have been fighting this thing all day. How would one make a sharp corner (1) and still keep the smooth curve when looking from the right (2)?

[image]

[image: screenshot]

Original shape:
[image: screenshot2]

The curve I want, but it lacks the sharp corner from the first picture:
[image]

Comment: I would not do it with edge creases as you often won't be able to fix all the problems you'll meet, maybe show the original shape?

Comment: Apply crease to the horizontal edge or add a bevel

Comment: From your image goal and the original, you dont have enough geometry to get your final goal. [See](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/280978/i-am-having-issues-with-subdivision-surface/280981#280981) and [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220293/problem-with-subdivision-modifier-making-a-hard-edge-have-curves-between-each-ve/220297#220297) and [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/226781/modelling-with-subdivide/226788#226788)

Comment: Ah... It's still a mystery for me how more geometry will help. Where do I add loopcuts or bevels?

Comment: Well, you just need to check the correct shape that you need and practice the amount of geometry that you need, you also don't necessarily need creases https://imgur.com/a/PleRCls

Comment: Oh that I understand! (thanks for the image), but it still doesn't have that sharp corner (1) from my first image. The first image is pretty much the right shape, except that the sharp corner isn't going with the curve when you look at it from this angle https://imgur.com/a/SfYvWp8

Comment: This https://imgur.com/a/SOvRstm is what I need, but without the subdivision applied and modified. Is that possible?

Comment: Hello why don't you do it with topology instead of creases?

Comment: Like this? https://imgur.com/a/SOvRstm More faces makes the object harder to modify. I'd prefer to keep it low poly if that is possible